# Find out who calling from my iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, core-telephony

Is there any possibility to find out who is calling when my app is launched or in background (doesn't matter). Generally can I get contact name ( John Doe for example ) from code ? I search the Core Telephony Framework but there is just an CallID property in CTCall - but nothing like contact.

Thanks!

Comment: it seems to be unreachable from Core Telephony Framework.
But can i get access to recent calls from my PhoneApp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get who is calling. There is not offical api for that. May be you can do it in jailbreak.

Comment: Yeah i knew about call_history.db and you can get that just with jailbreak...
/private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db

I'm searching for legal solution :-)

Comment: You will not get Public api for same. And if you use any third party or private api, then your app will be rejected by apple.

Answer (score 0):

Its `not possible` in `iOS`.

But in `jailbreak` it might be `possible`. I don't know about that.